Load center and main breaker sharing same lugs at service entrance
The load center supplies 80% of the house,200 amp main breaker suppling hvac and wh with 2 subpanels for heat exchanger and water well.I recently split 2 over loaded circuits on load center creating 2 new 20 amp circuits that I ran to main breaker. 200amp panel did not have an earth ground and was bonded with screw,so when tested showed open ground so I installed 8ft ground rod in earth and new circuits still show open ground???????

The triple-tapping the main lugs is horrible.  And completely unnecessary, since the subpanel feeders tapped off the service wires could have simply been placed on a circuit breaker. There's plenty of room and the breakers are $15.
By the way, there are times you tap service wires, such as solar or a type 1 surge suppressor... but they make feeder taps for that which clamp onto the wire and prick the insulation.  The people doing this just didn't know any better.
I would contact the utility and ask for a meter pull to replace the main breaker - that's a routine job that shouldn't hang you up on permits and inspections.  Then get those wires out of there and re-torque the proper service wires with a torque wrench.  Reroute the feeders to breakers.
Also, white hot wires. Those should be marked with black tape.  Mark one of them red if you really want to be fancy LOL, but black is fine. Teccccchnically, if they are #6 or smaller they should be native black wire, but that's the least of my concerns here.
Now you may think "wait, if I move these from the service wire to e.g. a 60A breaker in my main panel for the #6 wire, doesn't that add 60 amps to my service Load Calculation which is already pretty stuffed on this panel"?  No.  That's not how Load Calculations work.  For the main panel Load Calculation, the subpanels are disregarded, and the loads in those subpanels are examined. E.G. if I run a 90A feeder to my garage and put a 16A EV charge station out there (plenty for 95% of people), that counts as 16A not 90A.
That aside, each subpanel gets its own Load Calculation to determine the required size of its feeder.
As far as 4-wire feeders to the subpanels, this work obviously pre-dates 1999 when 4-wire feeders to same-building subpanels became mandatory. So it's "leeegal" as is, but it would be good to retrofit a ground wire and split neutrals and grounds on the subs.  E.G. that Federal Pacific - kill it with fire before it kills you with fire.
You mentioned concerns about system grounding.  That "3-light tester" you are using doesn't know if your system grounding and Grounding Electrode System is any good. It doesn't care.  It only knows whether neutral and ground connect to each other back at the main panel.   So if you are getting an "Open Ground" indication, that means that the ground has not made it to a place connected to the neutral bar.  In the main panel, grounds are allowed as a guest on the neutral bar, so if that's where it's going and the neutral too, you just have to do old-fashioned wire tracing to find the break there.

The open ground is the least of your worries right now
Your problem is far larger than an open ground.  Best I can tell, you have both your "sub"panels improperly tapped off the service wires, and the subpanel you posted a photo of is of the Fire Protection Eliminated variety atop that.  In other words, you have a known-bad panel type hot-wired to your service line.
I'd get those two subpanels on proper feeder breakers ASAP, then get that FPE subpanel replaced shortly thereafter, and only then start troubleshooting what problems remain.  Fixing other stuff isn't going to do you any good when one of those FPE breakers fails to trip and lets a fault go incendiary on you.

Yes load center needs to go.. So should I replace with subpanl with feeder breaker in 200amp panel and separate N and G. Or should I extend wiring nutted and in inclosure to main breaker panel????

@markmeyers -- the former is your best bet
